# Structure of skew $0,\pm1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $S$ be a skew symmetric matrix with entries from $\{-1,0,+1\}$. We know that there is a unitary matrix $U$ that diagonalizes $S$. There are only $3^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}$ such matrices and still lower distinct matrices.

Can one expect any structure to $U$?